# getSelection() don't work in UIWebView iframe

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

In my iOS app inside there is a UIWebView and I can not to get the selected text using javascript. In detail, I return the selected text but I lose it when I tap a button.

Any suggestions?

Comment: At touchend event I would have the selected text ...

Comment: If it is within an iframe inside an HTML document within the UIWebView then you will need to access the iframe first. For instance, using jQuery and assuming it is the first iframe in the DOM, you could try this:

    $('iframe').get(0).contentWindow.getSelection().toString();